# FileNotFound Exception in FileOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, swingworker

I'm getting error of FileNotFound. Basically, I'm trying to upload file from client to server.

Please, help me with it.

This is client.java class
package ftppackage;

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Client { 

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException { 
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",15123); 
        File transferFile = new File ("D:\\AsiaAd.wmv");
        byte [] bytearray = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending Files...");
        os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("File transfer complete");
    }
}
```

And this is my server.java class

```
package ftppackage;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int filesize=1022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15123);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
        byte [] bytearray = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\0\\"); // it is creating new file not copying the one from client
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        currentTot = bytesRead;
        do {
            bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
            if(bytesRead >= 0)
                currentTot += bytesRead;
        } while(bytesRead > -1);
        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Plus, guide me how do add progress bar in it with percentage. I read about SwingWorker here but unable to implement it as I'm totally new with threading concepts. 
Thank you for considering my questions.

Comment: The text of the `FileNotFoundException` gives you the reason. Probably a permission problem, but only you can tell as you haven't posted it. You need to look at `ProgressMonitorInputStream`.

Comment: When I add randomFile.ext means any random file then, it is created. if there is permission problem for writing in E:/0 then, why some random file is created ?

Comment: I don't understand a word of that, but you should have taken the hint and inspected the exception text, or indeed posted it here.

Comment: Show us exception callstack and exact exception message.

Answer (score -1):

FileNotFoundException is something you will get if you point the File Object to some File which is not existing in that path. it means what ever the file you are trying to upload in not there in the specified path. SO make sure you give a valid path.

Comment: I'm trying to upload file from client to server. Keeping the copy of client file on server upload path prior to upload doesn't make sense at all. Server should simply copy the file sent by client.